# Is there a version of the Black Moon Clan arc saying the Moon Kingdom were extraterrestrials that used biological engineering to create humans?

Tags: sailor-moon

I have [read on a forum](https://forums.sufficientvelocity.com/threads/dungeon-keeper-ami-sailor-moon-dungeon-keeper.31639/post-15201358) that, during the Black Moon Clan arc/second season of *Sailor Moon*, it's revealed that humans were created by the Moon Kingdom using biological engineering and that the Moon Kingdom wasn't from Earth, but came from elsewhere in space.

Is that true? And if it's wrong about when that reveal happened, is there *any* continuity in which this reveal occurs?

Comment: Your edit to the title has just made the title more confusing. You're asking whether there's an adaptation of the Black Moon Clan arc, in any continuity, that reveals that humans were created by the Moon Kingdom using bio-engineering?

Comment: @F1Krazy - I see that edit! The "Moon Kingdom is aliens, aliens that created humans" is also important, so gonna use your edit as a base...